# Detect only Tablet in WP

Tags: front-end, mobile

I have an annoying issue, I can detect mobile devices ( with wp_is_mobile() ) on WordPress.  But I want to detect only Tablet devices. How can I do it?

Comment: It looks like wp_is_mobile guesses from the User-Agent string. You'd have to write something similar for tablets I suppose, or use a database of User-Agents such as [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) to identify the device. (WURFL is the one I've used before, and it's very thorough and the database is updated weekly.  I don't think it's free though, and I expect others are available.)

Comment: What exactly is it you need to know about the device - the resolution, orientation, touch screen? Maybe you can detect something else.

Comment: Hi @rup, thank you for your response, I have several videos on my website for each device ( Desktop, Tabet and Mobile ) and I want to show them on their device, for example, show Tablet Video just only in Tablet Device and etc.